# Ubuntu 16 Gnome terminal .bashrc source issues

Tags: bash, ubuntu, gnome-terminal

I have written a script to automate the installation of a program/project (consisting of several programs along with different dependencies). I ran into the problem of .bashrc not being sourced during the script (despite source ~/.bashrc) leading to path errors. This was solved by forcing the script to run in interactive mode with the -i flag as it seem to be a more clean method than changing the interactive check in the .bashrc file.

Once the program is fully installed I try to launch it in a new terminal but run into the .bashrc sourcing problem of path errors to packages. The .bashrc does not seem to load correctly, I've added echos in it to check if it gets read at all and every echo from first to last line gets printed out into the terminal. If I manually run source ~/.bashrc and then run the program again the path errors are solved.

From looking around and running shopt login_shell (returns OFF) my understanding is that my terminal (gnome) is running non-login interactive shells by default. Therefore .profile and the like are not loaded as it is a non-login shell, it should only be the bash.bashrc and .bashrc files that load. When I add the paths or add source ~/.bashrc to bash.bashrc the program runs in a new terminal without path errors. However this does not feel like a good solution as I think the .bashrc should be able to load properly and I believe the bash.bashrc ought not be edited. Is there anything that i've missed or a way to make the bashrc sourcing work? Does the interactive flag for the installation script effect this?

In essence: bashrc is not sourced in a new terminal unless I manually source it. Alternatively if the paths or bashrc sourcing is added to the bash.bashrc file it works without the manual sourcing. I'm lost as to why the bashrc is not sourced in a new terminal and I can't seem to find any solution from looking around.

Comment: can you add whatever you have in *.bashrc* to *.bash_profile* and try again?

Comment: Does the script start with #!/bin/bash ? What happens if you invoke the script by doing bash script.sh without sourcing? how about adding -x to the start of the script to turn on debugging / invokte it with bash -x myscript.sh?

Comment: I tried the .bash_profile without any success. From my understanding, the bash_profile does not load when the shell is an interactive non-login shell. Only bash.bashrc and .bashrc will be loaded?

Yes the script starts with #!/bin/bash. I'm not sure I understand the bash script.sh comment? it's an installation script so it's only run once (takes about 2 hours). I haven't tried running it with the -x flag, i'll try adding the paths and export to a new script and run it and check the results. Thanks.